# Search for values matching multiple criterias in VBA (Access)

Tags: vba, ms-access

First of all the table-setup:

```
ID (AI)
Question (Text)
Type (INT)
```

I already have a working query which looks like this:

```vb
Q2 = DLookup("[Question]", "tblQuestions", "[ID] = 2")
```

Now i want to adapt a second criteria to this search query as described in the manual:

```vb
Q2 = DLookup("[Question]", "tblQuestions", "[ID] = 2 AND [Type] = " & Me.Typefield)
```

(I tried Me.Typefield as well as Me.Typefield.Value)

What am i doing wrong?

BR

Comment: what datatype is TYPE? if it's a string you'll need quotes around the value you're trying to match

Comment: INT as described in the initial question. The field which i get the value from (Me.Typefield is an OptionGroup which consists out of radio buttons). If i just add one criteria (Me.Typefield) i get the corresponding results, but it wont work with 2 parameters

Comment: DLOOKUP isn't taking the typefield value from the table, it's taking it from the control called typefield on the form on which it sits, it's Me.typefield, not tablename.typefield

Comment: If you created proerly your OptionGroup, each option is asigned to a value you defined, and property Me.OptionGroup.Value should return the value of selected option. If there is no option selected, it will return a Null Value. What values have you assigned to each option of your group? Is there an option selected when you execute this code?